# Passing a class type by reference

Tags: swift5

So I want I my base tableView, upon which I've derived others, to centralize drag-n-drop operations.  Each of these tableViews have a distinct array controller as its dataSource, with each item class conforming to pasteboard reading and writing protocols.

But I'm stuck on its setup

```
override func mouseDragged(with event: NSEvent) {
    let arrayController = self.dataSource as! NSArrayController
    let itemClass = arrayController.objectClass
    let objects = arrayController.arrangedObjects as! [itemClass]
    let indexSet = self.selectedRowIndexes
    var items = [NSDraggingItem]()

    for index in indexSet {
        let item = NSDraggingItem.init(pasteboardWriter: objects[index])
        items.append(item)
    }
    self.beginDraggingSession(with: items, event: event, source: self)
}
```

as I get an error ?

[image]

Comment: Does `as! [NSPasteBoardWriting]` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer:** This just isn't how Swift works, cast (`as?` or `as!`) to an appropriate compile time type – in this case from the use of `objects` in `NSDraggingItem.init(pasteboardWriter: objects[index])` that is probably `[NSPasteBoardWriting]`

**Longer Answer:**

You may have just made a simple error, we all do sometimes, and the short answer is enough. But if you are wondering *why* your code isn't accepted maybe this will help and hopefully not confuse!

What you are trying to do is a form of *dynamic typing*, you set `itemClass` to a type that at *compile time* nothing is known about except that it is *some* class type.

At its core Swift is essentially a *statically typed* language, it works by either knowing everything about the type of something, e.g. when something is declared to have a particular reference or value type; by knowing something about the type, e.g. when something has a protocol type; or even nothing, e.g. when something is of unconstrained generic parameter type *and* in all these cases what can be done is largely limited by this knowledge.

Variable types are not supported; while there are less specific types, e.g. the `AnyClass` in the example, operations specific to the actual runtime type of something cannot be performed until a cast to that specific (compile time known) type is made (with `as?` or `as!`)

Swift does support some dynamic typing features, notably in its support for parts of Objective-C – which has both statically and dynamically typed parts; but these do not give you what you are trying to do here, that is cast to a type unknown until runtime.

You probably know Objective-C, a simple example of how the two languages differ in static/dynamic approach is what happens when a method/function is called. For Objective-C method dispatch is dynamic, the compiled code performs a *search* for the implementation of the method and that search may *fail* resulting in a runtime error and abort. In Swift (excluding its interworking with Objective-C) when a function is called the compiled code does *not* search, the implementation is known to exist at compile time and there can by no runtime error and abort.

To do what you are attempting you need to determine at *design time* what type you need to perform the desired operation (construct an `NSDraggingItem` in this case)  and whether you either absolutely know or maybe know the value you have will at runtime conform to that type. If you *absolutely* know you can use the `as!` cast, which will abort execution if you are wrong, or you can use the `as?` which allows you to test for success and take appropriate action if you have something of unplanned type.

HTH

Comment: Yes, objC, .... it's different; and yes to a dynamic typing inference. But, In my case the objects do conform to the writing protocol, so the suggestion: `as! [NSPasteboardWriting]` affirms the protocol conformance - both now (design) & then (run-time).  I hope you agree.

Answer (score 0):

I will posit my own answer with the [Sweeper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5133585/sweeper)'s suggestion and [CRD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/568283/crd)'s excellent commentary.

The source objects, conform to the pasteboard writing protocol - NSPasteboardWriting; I mandate it.  The target casting confirms this.  My issue was a noob case of thinking objC, and cast at source vs target but enforcing just the same; I hope ;-).

```
override func mouseDragged(with event: NSEvent) {
    let arrayController = self.dataSource as! NSArrayController
    let objects = arrayController.arrangedObjects as! [NSPasteboardWriting]
    let delegate = self.delegate as! NSViewController
    let indexSet = self.selectedRowIndexes
    var items = [NSDraggingItem]()

    for index in indexSet {
        let dragImage = (delegate.view.window?.windowController?.document as! Document).displayImage!
        let item = NSDraggingItem.init(pasteboardWriter: objects[index])
        item.setDraggingFrame(self.rect(ofRow: index), contents: dragImage)
        item.draggingFrame = self.rect(ofRow: index)
        items.append(item)
    }
    self.beginDraggingSession(with: items, event: event, source: self)
}
```